# expected value (Sheldon Ross 9th edition)

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value

A person buy 10 lottery tickets with each having a winning probability p. If he wins a prize in atleast one of the tickets,he gets addicted and will keep on buying tickets till he wins again. Find the expected number of tickets he buys.

**My attempt :**

Let A be the event that he wins atleast once in the first 10 tickets bought.

$ \therefore \: P(A)=(1-(1-p)^{10}) \quad and \quad P(A^c)=(1-p^{10}) \\ $

Let Y be the number of tickets bought after 10th ticket, Y can thus take values 0,1,2,3,......

Solving the equation E(10+Y) gives :

$\\$

E(10+Y)=$10+E(Y) \\ =10+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}iP(Y=i) \\ 
since \: A \cup A^c = \Omega ,using\: law \: of \: total \: probability \: \colon   \\ =10+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i[P(Y=i\cap A) \cup (Y=i \cap A^c)] \\ =10+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i[P(A)P(Y=i| A) + P(A^c)P(Y=i|A^c)]  \\ = 10+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i[(1-(1-p)^{10}) P(Y=i| A) + (1-p^{10}) P(Y=i|A^c)] \\   =  10+(1-(1-p)^{10})\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}iP(Y=i| A) \\ $

Y=i|A is a geometric random variable with i = 1,2,3,4,.....

E(10+Y) = $ =  10+(1-(1-p)^{10})\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i(1-p)^{i-1}p \\ =10+[(1-(1-p)^{10})/p]  \\$

But the answer to it given in Ross is : $10+[p(1-(1-p)^{10})/(1-p)^2]$

Is the anwer given wrong or am i making some mistake, can you please point out the mistake i made. Many thanks.

Comment: In general, it holds that $P(A^c)$ _equals_ $1-P(A)$. Have you checked whether your $P(A) = 1 - (1-p)^{10}$ and $P(A^c) = 1-p^{10}$ satisfy this pesky theoretical requirement?

Comment: i have edited the answer with the details. can you plz tell if it's right, or can you please point out the mistake